# Octopus Deploy substitute variables in a jar file

Tags: java, spring, azure, spring-boot, octopus-deploy

I'm trying to use octopus deploy to deploy a java application on to Azure. I have a situation where I need to set few values dynamically using octopus in a yml file. I'm using Spring Boot externalized configuration to read the values from yml file.

Problem: I need to update the yml file which is packed inside a jar with variables defined in octopus.

Does anyone have any idea on how to achieve this?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Java and jar files, but if some cmdline tool can extract that file and write it back, you can do that with Java. But why are you using Octopus to deploy Java apps? that's ridiculous.

Comment: Yes, use @4c74356b41 's suggestion. FWIW, plenty of people use Octopus for Java (although it's usually where they're also doing .NET).
The other option is to externalize the yml file so you can deal with them independently (externalizing configuration is a common pattern).

Comment: @Damovisa thank you, I think externalizing yml is a good idea

Answer (score 1):

This is a feature that Octopus Deploy supports OOTB see [here](http://docs.octopusdeploy.com/display/OD/Substitute+Variables+in+Files)